# How to wait for a download task to finish in swift 3

Tags: swift, asynchronous, semaphore, nsurlsession

I am trying to build a user regeistration form, which should check if the user already exists. So I am sending a php request to my my mysql server. If the return value is empty, the user does not exists yet.

Unfortunatley I am really stuck with waiting for this check to finish. I tried several solutions I found googleing but none of them worked. My current code uses semaphores and will crash with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", so the semaphore is not waiting until the task is finished as I would expect it.

Any hints, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

```
private func isUniqueEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    var result: Bool?
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    let requestURL = URL(string: "http://localhost/firstpostget/functions/get.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postParameters = "email=" + email
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        var myJson: AnyObject
        do{
            myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
            if myJson.count == 0{
                result = true
                semaphore.signal()
            } else{
                result = false
                semaphore.signal()
            }
        } catch{
            //TODO
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    return result!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is async and you are force unwrapping nil value so this is the reason it crashes.

You have to change your function implementation to also be async, for example using closures:

```
private func isUniqueEmail(email: String, completion: ((Bool) -> (Void))?) {
    let requestURL = URL(string: "http://localhost/firstpostget/functions/get.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postParameters = "email=" + email
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        var myJson: AnyObject
        do{
            myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
            if myJson.count == 0 {
                completion?(true)
            } else{
                completion?(false)
            }
        } catch{
            //TODO
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now you can use this function in this way:

```
isUniqueEmail(email: "aaa@bbbb.com") { result in
    if result {
        print("email unique")
    } else {
        print("email not unique")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, actually I need to use the Bool to validate the result and not only print it to the console. And I can't do that with your solution.

Comment: Of course you can. You have your bool inside result variable

Comment: Yes but I can't give it outside that function. I can call it where you put the print statement. But if I give it over to a variable outside that function it will take too long again. For example if I do `test: Bool = false; isUniqueEmail(email: "aaa@bbbb.com") { result in test = result} print(test)` test will still be false even if result is true.

Comment: It's async task via internet - it cannot be instant. You have to add some sort of loader and just wait for the completion, also you have to prepare to not receive any response because of some network error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rethink the pattern you're using to get the data out of your request, you should consider using a custom handler/callback method that you pass along with the email you're trying to check. See below for an example:

```
private func isUniqueEmail(email: String, handler: ((_ result: Bool) -> Void)?) -> Void {
    let requestURL = URL(string: "http://localhost/firstpostget/functions/get.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postParameters = "email=" + email
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
        var myJson: AnyObject
        var result: Bool = false
        do{
            myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

            if myJson.count == 0 {
                result = true
            }

            guard handler != nil else {
                return
            }

            handler!(result)

        } catch{
            //TODO
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Run:**

```
isUniqueEmail(email: "test@test.com", handler: { result in
    print(result) // true || false
})
```

If you really want to go down the "wait" route then take a took at `DispatchGroup`'s

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Answer (score 0):

**you can use URlSession  like :**

```
     func isUniqueEmail(email: String,completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/firstpostget/functions/get.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=\(email)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)


    // loading to wait request
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        // we get request request

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            completion(false)

            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
           completion(false)
        }else{

            completion(true)

        }


        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }



    task.resume()
}
```

**and used in code Like**

```
self.isUniqueEmail(email: "your Email") { (isExit) in

    if isExit {


    }else{


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really get your answer. I can't see the check anymore if there is any response to the request and no matter what I type in the if isExit is always executed.

Comment: You will call this method if there is response isExit is true if not it will be false

Comment: It is not working then. No matter if there is an response or not isExit is always true.

Comment: Sorry code updated i forget if else in function check again

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

**ApihelperClass**

```
static let sharedInstance = ApihelperClass()

typealias CompletionHandler = (_ success:Bool, _ error:Bool, _ result:NSDictionary) -> Void
typealias ErrorHandler =  (_ success: Bool, _ error:Bool) -> Void

    func callPostRequest(_ urlPath: String, params:[String: AnyObject], completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler, errorHandler:@escaping ErrorHandler ){

        print("urlPath:==> \(urlPath) ")
        let session = Foundation.URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: urlPath)
        var request = URLRequest(url : url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        do {

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

                    guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        errorHandler(false, true)
                        return
                    }

                    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                        //                            print("response = \(response)")
                    }

                    let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

                    if let responsedata = responseString!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as? Data{

                        do {

                            let jsonResult:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responsedata, options: []) as! NSDictionary
                            print("Get The Result \(jsonResult)")
//parse your jsonResult as per your requirements 
                            if error != nil {
                                print("error=\(error)")

                                completionHandler(false, true, jsonResult)//
                            }


                            if let str = jsonResult["success"] as? NSNull {
                                print("error=\(str)")

                                completionHandler(false, true, jsonResult)

                            }
                            else {
                                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                                //                                    print("Response string : \(responseString)")
                                completionHandler(true, false, jsonResult)
                            }



                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) .resume()
        }catch {
                print("Error ->Catch")
        }
    }
```

**Add to your viewcontroller**

```
func isUniqueEmail(email: String){
    ApihelperClass.sharedInstance.callPostRequest("http://localhost/firstpostget/functions/get.php", params: ["email":email as AnyObject], completionHandler: { (success, error, result) in
        //success 200
    }) { (success, error) in
        //error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Where would I put the Apihelper Class?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found a solution. My semaphore approach actually worked as well as dispatchgroups. The task just needed to be `URLSession.shared.dataTask`

Still thank's a lot for all the answers.